# Custom events tracking in Google analytics

Tags: android, events, google-analytics

I want to track events to Google analytics from from my application. The problem is that I have limited options Category, Action, Label and Value.

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
    .setAction(getString(actionId))
    .setLabel(getString(labelId))
    .build());
```

Is there any way to customize this event so that I can track event according to my preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can add `setCustomDimension` for example:

```
    HitBuilders.EventBuilder eventBuilder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder();
    eventBuilder.setCustomDimension(1, my_pref_1);
    eventBuilder.setCustomDimension(2, my_pref_1);
    eventBuilder.setCustomDimension(3, my_pref_1);
```

Comment: how can i view these custom dimensions on Analytics Dashboard?

Comment: You can read about the custom dimension: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets. Generally you need first to go to Admin -> Custom dimension -> Add your custom values, then use the id you get as the id in your code. like in my example